# Get Email From Hunter.io user Zapier Code Step

Tags: zapier

I'm trying to use Zapier to call the Hunter.io API and return the first email. Since Zapier is pretty linear I need to be able to return individual emails. When I run this I get the following error "We had trouble sending your test through. Please try again. Error: 
You must return a single object or array of objects." I realize I put my API key in there - its only linked to a free version so don't go wild :-).

Any help is appreciated.

```
fetch('https://api.hunter.io/v2/domain-search?domain=' + inputData.website + '&api_key=11b44ca200c3b3ac0b5cf08091bce3346acd2ed3')
      .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        callback(null, json.emails);
      })
      .catch(callback);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Luckily this is an easy fix - it looks like the json that comes back has top-level `data` and `meta` keys, the former of which has the `emails`, you're looking for. If you change your successful callback to

```
callback(null, json.data.emails)
```

you should be good to go. **Note** that subsequent steps will run for each email returned during each run of the zap and no deduplication happens. Make sure whatever's downstream of this can happen a lot without consequences!

Also you'll definitely want to regenerate your API Key once this is resolved. Definitely not something you want floating around. :)

Comment: Any way to only execute the following steps for the first returned result? Thanks!

Comment: Sure! just return the first email: `callback(null, json.data.emails[0])`

Comment: When I test the step with your code it passes, but when it actually runs I get "You must return a single object or array of objects."

Comment: Huh. It worked fine for me using their example response from the docs ([here](https://gist.github.com/xavdid/7bf9d0487e2d85e7ced80dd8d16dab67)). My guess is maybe you're finding a domain that doesn't have any emails associated with it? In that case, you'd want to be more defensive: `callback(null, json.data.emails[0] || [])`

Comment: All that said, there's a Hunter zapier app ([here](https://zapier.com/apps/hunter/integrations)) that will probably handle all of this for you rather than you needing to debug on your own